# How to use self-signed SSL-certificate in python requests -- (raises SSLError)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

## Issue

When using python's `requests` library with a self-signed certificate, I am receiving an SSLError. The certificate does however work with curl.

I was hoping someone might have some suggestions, thank you very much for reading.

access website from curl (success)

```sh
curl -X GET 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/test'
# connection successful!
```

All attempts from python-requests fail (unless `verify=False` is set)

```py
url = 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/test'
requests.get(url)                                             # default
requests.get(url, verify='server.crt')                        # cert
requests.get(url, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt') # bundle

os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
requests.get(url)
```

error message:

```py
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /test 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

## Additional Details

In case it is relevant, here is how I generated, and trusted the certificate:

generate certificate

```sh
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

openssl req -new \
    -out server.csr \
    -key server.key \
    -config openssl.cnf

openssl x509 \
    -req days 21915 \
    -in server.csr \
    -signkey server.key \
    -out server.crt \
    -extensions v3_req \
    -extfile openssl.cnf
```

openssl.cnf

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = CA
stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = ON
localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = Ottawa
organizationalUnitName  = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  = Domain Control Validated
commonName = Example
commonName_max  = 64

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.com
DNS.2 = *.example.com
DNS.3 = localhost
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = ::1
```

install/trust certificate (ubuntu-16.04)

```sh
sudo cp server.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

host website

```sh
gunicorn \
    `# misc other settings` \
    --certfile server.crt \
    --keyfile server.key \
    flaskapp:app
```

Comment: I have the exact same question